# Using a Set data structure in React's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, set

Is it possible to use ES6's `Set` data structure in React?

For example, if I have a checklist composed of distinct items, and I'd like to maintain each item's checked state. I'd like to write something like this:

```
export default class Checklist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: new Set()
    }
  }

  addItem(item) {
    //...?
  }

  removeItem(item) {
    //...?
  }

  getItemCheckedStatus(item) {
    return this.state.checkedItems.has(item);
  }

  // More code...
}
```

I understand there may be a problem with the fact that a Set is mutable by nature, and React performs a shallow comparison when updating the component, so it expects immutable objects to be passed and held in the state. However, is there a way to hold and maintain a Set object in the state?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Since react will identify state changes only if the state property was replaced, and not mutated (shallow compare), you'll have to create a new Set from the old one, and apply the changes to it.

This is possible since `new Set(oldSet) !== oldSet`.

```js
const oldSet = new Set([1, 2]);
const newSet = new Set(oldSet);

console.log(oldSet === newSet);
```

---

How you use a Set in a class component:

```
export default class Checklist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: new Set()
    }
    
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem(item) {
    this.setState(({ checkedItems }) => ({
      checkedItems: new Set(checkedItems).add(item)
    }));
  }

  removeItem(item) {
    this.setState(({ checkedItems }) => {
      const newChecked = new Set(checkedItems);
      newChecked.delete(item);
      
      return {
       checkedItems: newChecked
      };
    });
  }

  getItemCheckedStatus(item) {
    return this.state.checkedItems.has(item);
  }

  // More code...
}
```

---

How to use a set with the `useState()` hook.

The example adds random integers between 1-5, and then removes random number in the same range.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Comp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => new Set());

  const addItem = item => {
    setState(prev => new Set(prev).add(item));
  }

  const removeItem = item => {
    setState(prev => {
      const next = new Set(prev);

      next.delete(item);

      return next;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addItem(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5))}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={() => removeItem(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5))}>Remove</button>
      <div>
        {Array.from(state)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Comp />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: There is an extra parens at the beginning of the remove item which is not needed since we're returning an object instead of altering the state directly. Thanks for the snippet!

Comment: @DBrown - I'm not sure what you're referring to. This is the [updater method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of setState. There was another error (actually mutating the state) that I've fixed.

Comment: I re-reviewed, and while I remember it being a syntax error in that method, I have a feeling it was from the previous function in some way on my end since I cannot replicate. Anyways, thanks again for the implementation blueprint!

Comment: Great answer! A small correction is needed only, the line below uses a semi-colon inside an object, which should be removed:
 `checkedItems: new Set(checkedItems).add(item);`

Comment: @OriDrori do you know if there's a way to render elements from set directly to jsx? In an array you would use `map` to achieve this, not sure about equivalent with sets.

Comment: To render Set's elements directly - `Array.from(set, item => //jsx)`

Answer (score 0):

`state` is just a common object, you can hold what ever you want in it.
You can overwrite the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method to implement it yourself. You can use you own logic to figure out if the component needs to update or not.
You don't even need to nest your set, you can just set it directly as the `state`:

```
this.state = new Set();
```