# Is it correct to use a Set() container in React state?

Tags: reactjs, data-structures, set

When using state in React, it is recommanded to keep it as [small as possible](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html)

Many time, I use javascript arrays to store for instance, a list of IDs in a React state.

```
state = {
    myListOfIDs: []
}
```

But in order to prevent duplicates, is it correct to use an [javascript Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) ? Or is it to heavy for React rendering ?

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482788/using-a-set-data-structure-in-reacts-state, you will have issues if you use sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot alter rendering, at most it can alter the reconciliation time of the virtual DOM, but I doubt you will see any difference. I have used Sets and it never impacted performance noticeably.

You can see sets as objects which values are `true`, i.e. `{1,2,3} ~ {1: true, 2: true, 3: true}`. If objects are ok to store state, so are sets.

If you are worried about the data structure you can always make your arrays contain only unique elements by casting twice:

```
a = [1,2,3,3,3]
b = new Set(a)  // {1,2,3}
c = [...b]  // [1,2,3]
```