# How to use Set with react's useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that I have to add/remove elements from, and I figured I would use `Set` to accomplish this because of its `add` `has` and `delete`.

```
const [tags, setTags] = React.useState(new Set())
```

If I want to add something to `tags`, how can I do this with `setTags`?  Or do I just call `tags.add()` ?

Comment: You can't since a Set is not an immutable data structure and React's state needs to be immutable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Set data structure in React's state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482788/using-a-set-data-structure-in-reacts-state)

Comment: Thanks!  So is it a bad idea to use Set if I have to re-create it each time?  It seems I'd have to clone a regular array as well, so I'm wondering which is preferred.

Comment: A `Set` stores unique values, so unless you want to code the part where you filter out duplicated values, creating a new `Set` each time would be ok.

Answer (score 59):

A `Set` is by definition mutable, React won't trigger a new render if you merely call `const newSet = set.add(0)` cause the shallow comparison between previous and new will always assert to `true`

You can use the `spread` operator to change references between each update yet still maintaining all of Set's behaviors

**Adding an element**

```
const [state, setState] = useState(new Set())

const addFoo = foo =>{
    setState(previousState => new Set([...previousState, foo]))
}
```

You could still use the `add` method since it returns the updated set

```
const addFoo = foo =>{
    setState(prev => new Set(prev.add(foo)))
}
```

---

**Removing an element**

`Removing` is a little trickier. You first need to turn it into an array, `filter` and spread the result

```
const removeFoo = foo =>{
    setState(prev => new Set([...prev].filter(x => x !== foo)))
}
```

For clarity

```
const removeFoo = foo =>{ 
    setState(prev =>{
        return prev.filter(x => x !== foo)
    })
}
```

Alternatively you can also make use of the delete methods as follows:

```
const removeFoo = foo =>{ 
  setState(prev => {
    prev.delete(foo);
    return new Set(prev);
  })
}
```

Comment: @Dupocas , why spread/filter inside of `Set` in `removeFoo`? Why you don't use `delete` method?

`const removeFoo = foo => setState(prev => new Set([...prev.delete(foo)]));`

Comment: I'd recommend preserving integrity of the prev state like so:
```const addFoo = foo => setState(prev => (new Set(prev)).add(foo))```
and
```const removeFoo = foo => setState(prev => (new Set(prev)).delete(foo))```

Comment: Can also easily do full set unions:
```const unionFoo = (fooArr) => setState(prev => {
  const s = new Set(prev);
  [...fooArr].forEach(s.add, s);
  return s;
})```
and differences:
```const differenceFoo = (fooArr) => setState(prev => {
  const s = new Set(prev);
  [...fooArr].forEach(s.delete, s);
  return s;
})```

Comment: Not sure about using `new Set(prev).delete(foo)` in the comment above - the return value of `Set.add()` is a Set but the return value of `Set.delete()` is a Boolean.

Comment: `setState(prev => (prev.delete(item), new Set(prev)))` solves the return type and is not cnsistent with the `Set.add` variant. or `setState(prev => new Set((prev.delete(item), prev)))`

Comment: why do you use `setState(prev => new Set(prev.add(foo)))`?
Is `setState(new Set(prev.add(foo)))` not enought?

Answer (score 11):

You have to create a new set, otherwise react won't know that it needs to rerender.  Something like the below will work.

```
setTags(tags => new Set(tags).add(tag))
```

Answer (score 10):

I followed the following approach and is working pretty well with my React Native component.

```
const DummyComponent = () => {
const [stateUserIds, setStateUseIds] = useState(new Set());

....
....

const handleUserSelected = user => {
    // Since we cannot mutate the state value directly better to instantiate new state with the values of the state
    const userIds = new Set(stateUserIds);

    if (userIds.has(user.userId)) {
      userIds.delete(user.userId);
    } else {
      userIds.add(user.userId);
    }
    setStateUseIds(userIds);
  };

....
....


return (
   <View> 
       <FlatList
          data={dummyUsers}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            const selected = stateUserIds.has(item.userId);
            return (
              
                <View style={{flex: 2}}>
                  <Switch
                    isSelected={selected}
                    toggleSwitch={() => handleUserSelected(item)}
                  />
                </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.userId.toString()}
        />
  </View>)

}
```

Hope this helps someone with same use Case.
Please refer to the following [Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dawn-zer82)

Comment: That looks good. A small improvement would be to remove "setStateUseIds(userIds)" from the if/else blocks and simply add it after the if/else, since it runs in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a set as your saved state (rerendering on each change to the set's membership) you can wrap up the techniques described above into a nice little hook that returns an object that behaves (almost...see below) like a set.

Specifically, I use the following custom hook:

```
const useSetState = (initial) => {
    const [set, setSet] = useState(new Set(...initial))
    return {
        add: el =>
            setSet((set) => {
                if (set.has(el)) return set
                set.add(el)
                return new Set(set)
            }),
        delete: el => {
            setSet((set) => {
                if (!set.has(el)) return set
                set.delete(el)
                return new Set(set)
            })
        },
        has: el => set.has(el),
        clear: () => setSet(new Set()),
        [Symbol.iterator]: () => set.values(),
        forEach: (fn) => set.forEach(fn),
        keys: () => set.keys(),
        values: () => set.values(),
        get size() {
            return set.size
        }

    }
}
```

You can use the hook like `const set = useSetState([])` and then call `set.add(el)`, `set.delete(el)` etc..

However, because of the way this hook is implemented the returned object isn't *quite* a set in that instanceof, Object.prototype.toString etc won't recognize it as a set (also, I didn't implement the thisArg of forEach).  If you really cared about this you could implement the same logic using proxies but that seems excessive for most applications imo

Answer (score 3):

I personally found the fact that all these solutions re-create the set on each modification, which is often counter productive. I wrote the below hook to get around this issue, and IMO having a piece of arbitrary state to trigger a re-render is less hacky than re-creating the set on each change:

```
function useSet<T>(initialValue?: T[]) {
    // a peice of state to trigger a re-render whenever the set changes
    // imo this is less hacky than re-creating the set on every state change
    const [_, setInc] = useState(false)

    //use a ref for the set instead
    const set = useRef(new Set<T>(initialValue))
    
    const add = useCallback(
        (item: T) => {
            if (set.current.has(item)) return
            setInc((prev) => !prev)
            set.current.add(item)
        },
        [setInc],
    )

    const remove = useCallback(
        (item: T) => {
            if (!set.current.has(item)) return
            setInc((prev) => !prev)
            set.current.delete(item)
        },
        [setInc],
    )

    return [set.current, add, remove] as const
}
```

The only downside here is if a consumer chooses to bypass the supplied `add` and `remove` methods and mutate the ref directly.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try using an object/array in place of a set. It should be noted that with objects insertion order is [not always preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/52499). But if you have a number of dynamically generated checkboxes and you receive a `change` event:

```
// set
function handleChange(e, name) {
  setSet(prv => e.target.checked
    ? new Set([...prv, name])
    : new Set([...prv].filter(v => v != name)));
}
// object
function handleChange(e, name) {
  setSet(prv => ({...prv, [name]: e.target.checked}));
}
// array
function handleChange(e, name) {
  setSet(prv => e.target.checked
    ? (prv.includes(text) ? prv : [...prv, text])
    : prv.filter(v2 => v2 != v));
}
```

Initialize:

```js
const [set, setSet] = useState(new Set);
const [set, setSet] = useState({});
const [set, setSet] = useState([]);
```

Add:

```js
setSet(prv => new Set([...prv, text]));
setSet(prv => ({...prv, [text]: true}));
setSet(prv => prv.includes(text) ? prv : [...prv, text]);
```

Remove:

```js
setSet(prv => new Set([...prv].filter(v2 => v2 != v)));
setSet(prv => ({...prv, [v]: false}));
setSet(prv => prv.filter(v2 => v2 != v));
```

Iterate:

```js
[...set].map(v => ...);
Object.keys(set).filter(v => set[v]).map(v => ...);
set.map(...);
```

The [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-fast-h0mbx?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto [@Peter Gerdes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926973/3921295), here is a TypeScript version of the hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useSetState = <T>(initial: T[]) => {
    const [set, setSet] = useState<Set<T>>(new Set(initial));
    return {
        add: (el: T) =>
            setSet((set) => {
                if (set.has(el)) return set;
                set.add(el);
                return new Set(set);
            }),
        delete: (el: T) => {
            setSet((set) => {
                if (!set.has(el)) return set;
                set.delete(el);
                return new Set(set);
            });
        },
        has: (el: T) => set.has(el),
        clear: () => setSet(new Set()),
        [Symbol.iterator]: () => set.values(),
        forEach: (callbackfn: (value: T, value2: T, set: Set<T>) => void, thisArg?: any) => set.forEach(callbackfn, thisArg),
        keys: () => set.keys(),
        values: () => set.values(),
        get size() {
            return set.size;
        },
    };
};
export default useSetState;
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for 2023

- Works just like `const set = new Set([...])`
- Maintains the same `Set` object throughout mutations and renders
- Provides access to all set methods and properties
- Typescript

Usage

```js
const Component = ({ ...props }: Props) 
  const set = useSet([1, 2, 3]);

  // ...
}
```

```js
// @/lib/use-state.ts

import { useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";

export function useSet<T>(initialValue: T[]) {
  const triggerRender = useState(0)[1];
  const set = useRef(new Set<T>(initialValue))
  return useMemo(() => ({
    add(item) {
      if (set.current.has(item)) return
      set.current.add(item)
      triggerRender(i => ++i)
    },
    delete(item) {
      if (!set.current.has(item)) return
      set.current.delete(item)
      triggerRender(i => ++i)
    },
    clear() {
      if (set.current.size === 0) return
      set.current.clear()
      triggerRender(i => ++i)
    },
    has: (item) => set.current.has(item),
    keys: () => set.current.keys(),
    values: () => set.current.values(),
    forEach: (...args) => set.current.forEach(...args),
    [Symbol.iterator]: () => set.current.values(),
    get size() { return set.current.size },
  }) as Set<T>, [])
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the triggerRender state value for the useMemo, so that the resulting set can be used in a useEffect dependency list.

Answer (score -9):

```
const [count, setCounter] = useState(0);
const [moreStuff, setMoreStuff] = useState();

const setCount = () => {
    setCounter(count + 1);
    setMoreStuff(...);

};
```