# How to conditionally disable check boxes

Tags: reactjs

I have a drop down with check boxes inside it (used Bootstrap). When two are checked, I want to make it so the users cannot check anymore until the others are unchecked. I attempted this using the disable attribute but keep getting the error below.

**What I tried:**

```
export default function Test() {
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
const [disableRadio, setDisableRadio] = useState(false);

function createCountryList() {
    const countries = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]; 
    return countries.map((country, key) => (
        <Form.Check
            disabled={disableRadio ? (e) => e.target.checked : false}
            key={key}
            label={country}
            onChange={(e) =>
                e.target.checked ? handleChecked(e) : handleUncheck(e)
            }
        />
    ));
}

function handleChecked(e) {
    const Arr = countries;
    Arr.push(e.target.value);
    setCountries(Arr);
    if (countries.length > 1) {
        setDisableRadio(true);
    } else {
        setDisableRadio(false);
    }
}

function handleUncheck(e) {
    const Arr = countries;
    const index = Arr.indexOf(e.target.value);
    Arr.splice(index, 1);
    setCountries(Arr);
}

return (
    <>
        <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
                {createCountryList()}
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    </>
);
```

}

**Getting this error:** `react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Invalid value for prop 'disabled' on <input> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.`

**What I want:**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This line doesn't really make sense: `disabled={disableRadio ? (e) => e.target.checked : false}`. The prop only expects a boolean: why are you passing a function in?

Comment: I use the arrow function because I wanted to see if the check box is checked or not. Sorry if I misunderstood how this all works. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, and I have a feeling that you're overcomplicating the handling of checkbox events.

1. You have `countries` as a state, and also as a fixed array of available countries. I'd suggest you store them separately: one is pure data (fixed array of available countries), and the other is the component state.
2. You can use `Set` to [handle adding/removing of countries, without too much of a fuss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806947/395910). There is no need to have separate event handlers for checked/unchecked states. We can handle adding/removing selected countries to the array using this logic below:

   ```
   const [countries, setCountries] = useState(new Set());

   function onChange(e) {
     if (e.target.checked) {
       setCountries(c => new Set([...c, e.target.value]));
     } else {
       setCountries(c => new Set([...c].filter(x => x !== e.target.value)))
     }
   }
   ```
3. There is no need to store `disableRadio` in a separate state. Instead, take advantage of `useMemo`, or simply use the logic of `countries.size > 1` in the template itself. Combine that with `countries.has(country)` to check whether a given checkbox's value is in the set of values. In this sense, a checkbox is disabled when (1) more than 1 countries have been selected AND (2) the count is NOT in the list of selected countries

   ```
   disabled={countries.size > 1 && !countries.has(country)}
   ```
4. Your checkbox options are missing the `value` attribute: remember to add that.

---

With all these changes proposed, your code can be simplified into something like this:

```
export default function Test() {
  // NOTE: Store available countries as a constant
  const availableCountries = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

  // NOTE: countries here refer to SELECTED countries
  //       We use new Set() so we automatically dedupe values
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(new Set());

  function createCountryList() {
    return availableCountries.map((country, key) => (
      <Form.Check
        disabled={countries.size > 1 && !countries.has(country)}
        key={key}
        value={country}
        label={country}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    ));
  }

  function onChange(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setCountries(c => new Set([...c, e.target.value]));
    } else {
      setCountries(c => new Set([...c].filter(x => x !== e.target.value)))
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
          {createCountryList()}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </>
  );
}
```

See example of CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit purple-microservice-9ksrm]

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer Terry! Sorry about the minor issues like missing a value.

Comment: @HarryS Happy to help, and there's nothing to apologise for :)