# Idiomatic way of triggering re-render on React `useState` hook without deep copying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Consider the following React functional component called `Test`:

```js
function Test() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(new Set());

  function handleClick() {
    data.add(42);
    setData(data);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>ADD 42</button>
      <p>{data.has(42) ? 'in set' : 'not in set'}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

The code above is affected by a common defect -- despite the intention of triggering a re-render via `setData(data)`, nothing will happen in practice as React doesn't check the contents of what `data` refers to, and `setData(data)` doesn't change any state.

The behavior can be seen live [**here** on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-elpa1v?file=App.tsx).

One possible workaround to achieve the desired behavior is to use `structuredClone` as follows:

```js
function handleClick() {
  data.add(42);
  setData(structuredClone(data));
}
```

Performing a deep copy of the `data` object will force React to perform a re-render. However, this solution performs an useless deep copy and it does not clearly communicate the intent of the developer.

**What is the idiomatic way to force React to render again in a situation like the above?**

For example, I would like something such as:

```js
function handleClick() {
  data.add(42);
  markAsDirty(data);
}
```

Comment: Check the idea of Spreading the Set to a new Set to change its reference. So React will know that it's changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806883/how-to-use-set-with-reacts-usestate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be treating React state as **immutable**. This means that if you want to add something to a Set, create a *new one*.

```
function Test() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(new Set());

  function handleClick() {
    const copy = new Set(data);
    copy.add(42);
    setData(copy);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>ADD 42</button>
      <p>{data.has(42) ? 'in set' : 'not in set'}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what `structuredClone` achieves, but I want to avoid the cost of an unnecessary deep copy at run-time.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo It's not a "deep copy". It's a shallow copy. The values in the old set are simply passed to the new set.

Comment: I see, so it's not as expensive as `structuredClone`.

Comment: a simple benchmark of array.slice vs set.new shows that it is 99.5% slower. Here is the benchmark i ran - https://gist.github.com/alexanderankin/7f631ae01a075f41df404f5cf3727239