# React State how to add elements (not single element) immutably to a javascript Set (not Array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have the a react state as follows

```
[ state, setState] = useState(new Set([1,2,3]))
```

I want to add a bunch of elements to the set immutably, how can I do that? It is simple with Arrays and can be just done using `setState(prev=>[...prev,...newElem])` but how do I do it in a set.

```
const newElems = new Set([4,5,6])  //These are new Elements that need to be appended
setState(prev=>new Set([..prev,...newElems]))   //This can be done and works but how do without converting Array to Set
```

The above implementation can be used, but how can it be done without the overhead of reassigning an Array to a Set every time. Can I just not append it somehow (immutably)

**P.S This question is different from the one in the link below as it is about adding multiple elements not a single one. Also it uses Hooks approach in React vs Class based approach, sure they are interchangeable, but this question is more up to date and might help others**
[Using a Set data structure in React's state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482788/using-a-set-data-structure-in-reacts-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sadly the case that `Set` objects have no standard way of adding *multiple* elements after constructing the set. They were originally intentionally created minimalist with the idea of expanding them as needed. While there are some proposals for some features on the table, an `addAll` method or similar isn't on that list. (**Yet**. Although there's nothing in the [proposals repo](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) yet, I think there's been talk of adding immutable-style methods to `Set` and `Map`, or possibly immutable peer classes instead.)

You can create a `Set` subclass with and `addAll` method:

```
class MySet extends Set {
    addAll(iterable) {
        for (const element of iterable) {
            this.add(element);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then the update would be:

```
setState(prev => new MySet(prev).addAll(newElem));
```

Live Example:

```js
class MySet extends Set {
    addAll(iterable) {
        for (const element of iterable) {
            this.add(element);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

const prev = new MySet();
prev.addAll([1, 2, 3]);
const newElem = [4, 5, 6]; // Or a `Set` or `MySet`

const set = new MySet(prev).addAll(newElem);
console.log([...set]);
```

Or you could add an optional argument to the constructor, but I'm always leery of adding arguments to subclass constructors:

```
class MySet extends Set {
    constructor(...iterables) {
        super();
        for (const iterable of iterables) {
            this.addAll(iterable);
        }
    }

    addAll(iterable) {
        for (const element of iterable) {
            this.add(element);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then the update would be:

```
setState(prev => new MySet(prev, newElem));
```

Live Example:

```js
class MySet extends Set {
    constructor(...iterables) {
        super();
        for (const iterable of iterables) {
            this.addAll(iterable);
        }
    }

    addAll(iterable) {
        for (const element of iterable) {
            this.add(element);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

const prev = new MySet();
prev.addAll([1, 2, 3]);
const newElem = [4, 5, 6]; // Or a `Set` or `MySet`

const set = new MySet(prev, newElem);
console.log([...set]);
```

Comment: @dracarys - Meh, the `...` should have been a clue for me! :-) I've fixed the answer now.

Comment: Thanks, I really like your implementation rather than just looping and adding in the setState callback

Answer (score 0):

The overhead is really minimal and shouldn't impact performance at all given the array size is not in thousands. Also, I am assuming you are using set as you are having a lot of checks whether certain element is present in set or not. So it is more like a tradeoff that you are having by using the set.

You can also have a look at [React Set state update answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482788/using-a-set-data-structure-in-reacts-state)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @TJ Crowder - I think the link I have attached has the same answer as you have given, if you could go through it, thanks.

Comment: If the only answer is in the link, that's now how SO works; answers must have the answer **in** them; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer. (But I've reviewed the answers there and they don't seem to really relate much.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the Set.add() function?  you can map or loop over newElem's elements, add them to a new set, and then set the new set in state again.

Comment: I **think** you mean: 1. Create new set, 2. Loop through old set and add the elements, 3. Add the new element. But it's really not clear from the answer, at first I thought you were suggesting just calling `add` on the existing set (which you can't do with React state), but a re-read suggests otherwise. But yes, that would work, though it's unnecessary code as `new Set` will do #2 for you.