# React PureComponent state with array vs set

Tags: reactjs, set, components

I'd like to be able to use a `PureComponent` which have a `Set` object in its state, and achieve a rerender each time that set's size is updated.

Currently, the following doesn't work:

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    items: new Set()
  };

  addItem = () => {
    this.setState(({ items }) => ({ items: this.state.items.add(Math.random()) }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Total Items {this.state.items.size}</div>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add item</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Note that when using an array, it works:

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    items: []
  };

  addItem = () => {
    this.setState(({ items }) => ({ items: [...items, Math.random()] }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Total Items {this.state.items.length}</div>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add item</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

What's needed to make the first snippet work?

Comment: Someone had the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482788/using-a-set-data-structure-in-reacts-state

Comment: @AC3, thanks, but that's not the case here. The only reason it doesn't work here is the use of pure component, which is not discussed in that question.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from: [Using a Set data structure in React's state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482788/using-a-set-data-structure-in-reacts-state)

The following will work because your state value is replaced with a new `Set` instead of mutating the original.

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    items: new Set()
  };

  addItem = () => {
    this.setState(({ items }) => ({ items: new Set(items).add(Math.random()) }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Total Items {this.state.items.size}</div>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add item</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The difference with using PureComponent is that it:

> ... only shallowly compares the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce false-negatives for deeper differences.

Because you've already mutated your state value inside of your `setState` callback React will think there are no changes when performing the shallow compare.

Comment: That's incorrect. If it wasn't PureComponent, it would work.

Comment: I made some changes to my answer, I hope it's clear why PureComponent gives different results.