# React.js State updating correctly only once, then failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, set, react-state, react-state-management

I have a parent and a child component. There are 3 props the parent provides out of which 1 is not updating correctly.

Following is the parent component. The prop in question is **selectedFilters** (which is an object where keys are mapped to **sets**) and the relevant update function is **filterChanged** (this is passed to the child)

```
import filters from "../../data/filters";    //JSON data

const Block = (props) => {
  const [selectedFilters, setSelectedFilters] = useState({versions: new Set(), languages: new Set()});
  console.log(selectedFilters);

  const filterChanged = useCallback((filter_key, filter_id) => {
    setSelectedFilters((sf) => {
      const newSFSet = sf[filter_key]; //new Set(sf[filter_key]);
      if (newSFSet.has(filter_id)) {
        newSFSet.delete(filter_id);
      } else {
        newSFSet.add(filter_id);
      }
      const newSF = { ...sf, [filter_key]: new Set(newSFSet) };
      return newSF;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <FilterGroup
      filters={filters}
      selectedFilters={selectedFilters}
      onFilterClick={filterChanged}
    ></FilterGroup>
  );
};

export default Block;
```

The following is the child component: (Please note that while the **Filter** component runs the filterChanged function, I think it is **irrelevant** to the error)

```
import Filter from "./Filter/Filter";

const FilterGroup = (props) => {
  const { filters, selectedFilters, onFilterClick } = props;
  console.log(selectedFilters);

  const filter_view = (
    <Container className={styles.container}>
      {Object.keys(filters).map((filter_key) => {
        const filter_obj = filters[filter_key];
        return (
          <Filter
            key={filter_obj.id}
            filter_key={filter_key}
            filter_obj={filter_obj}
            selectedFilterSet={selectedFilters[filter_key]}
            onFilterClick={onFilterClick}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Container>
  );

  return filter_view;
};

export default FilterGroup;
```

When running the application, I find that the selectedFilters updates correctly only once. After that, it only changes temporarily in the main **Block.tsx**, but eventually goes back to the first updated value. Also, **FilterGroup.tsx** only receives the first update. After that, it never receives any further updated values.

Here are the logs:
[image]

After some experimentation, it is clear that the problem originates from the **filterChanged** function. But I cannot seem to figure out why the second update is temporary AND does not get passed on to the child.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
(If any other info is required, pls do mention it)

Comment: Mutating the current `Set` before returning a new state still ends up mutating the previous state, which is an anti-pattern in React.

Comment: I see. So is that a possible reason for the issue? Because I still don't see why it would prevent the child component from getting the updated state.

Comment: You could start by trying to create the new Set from the old one first, then mutate that new Set, then return the new state. See [Using a Set data structure in React's state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44482788/1218980)

Comment: Correct! This did solve my problem. 
However, I am still not sure why the child component did not get the updated state. Like, what kind of comparison does React do that results in the child not getting any updates after the **first** time. 
That's my doubt

Comment: (This is an auto-comment suggesting that this question could be lined as a possible duplicate of the following question) Does this answer your question? [Using a Set data structure in React's state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482788/using-a-set-data-structure-in-reacts-state)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you actually want your `filterChanged` function to be wrapped with `useCallback`, especially with an empty deps array.  with the empty deps array, I believe `useCallback` will fire once on initial render, and memoize the result.  You may be able to add `filter_key` and `filter_id` to the dependency array, but useCallback tends to actually slow simple functions down, instead of adding any real performance benefit, so you may just want to get rid of the `useCallback` completely and switch `filterChanged` to a regular arrow function.

Comment: Actually that was just to get the hang of useCallback, and yes, I intend to make the resultant function be created only once. 
Also, I don't think the dep. array should be a problem since filter_key and filter_id are actually arguments passed by the child component, so the function doesn't need to change according to those arguments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `useCallback` uses closures to also keep the initial values of the arguments passed into the function.  You can either add `filter_key` and `filter_id` to the dependency array (which kind of defeats the purpose of using `useCallback` in this case, or not use `useCallback`

Comment: `useCallback` is more for when you have a *child component* that's very expensive to rerender, and you're passing a function as a prop to it.  Since React will check that props are deeply equal, (and for functions the equality check is by reference), the most common use case for `useCallback` is an *expensive child component* that needs a simple function passed to it as a prop. Without useCallback, the child would rerender on ever render of the parent, since the function will have a different reference each time.

Comment: You are right about the closure. However, as mentioned before, since filter_key and filter_id are actually arguments passed by the child component, the function doesn't need to change according to those arguments. 
It's only when the function depends on a variable that's defined outside the block scope, when we need to add the variable to the dep. array